# Play video from a UNIX SOCKET using gstreamer (gst-launch-1.0)

Tags: gstreamer, unix-socket, gst-launch, gst-launch-1.0

I need to play video from a UNIX SOCKET using gstreamer (gst-launch-1.0)

example

```
gst-launch-1.0 socketsrc socket-path=/tmp/unixSocket  ! queue max-size-buffers=0 max-size-time=0 max-size-bytes=0 min-threshold-buffers=0 !  h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
```

Is it possible?
I don't know how to specify that socketsrc get the data from a unix socket

Comment: what isn't work? and what does the stream look like that is writing to that socket?

Comment: According to the documentation there is no `socket-path` property. You need to specify a `socket` (https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tcp/socketsrc.html?gi-language=c#socketsrc:socket), which is a GSocket. So I suspect this is not possible from the cli, i.e., using gst-launch. You'd have to write some code.